# Solspace Calendar

Tags: solspace-calendar, events

I'm very new to ExpressionEngine and do not understand how this works. Currently on our site, whenever an event is posted, it gets updated in the "upcoming events" section on the homepage. However, when it has expired it still shows up and doesn't drop off until midnight.

For example, all our events are from 10:30pm - 4am. We want it to drop off at 4am but instead it waits till midnight to drop off.

Can anyone help with that? This is the code that is being used to embed the upcoming events. I didn't create the site, a third party company did and I wasn't hired back then so I have no idea who worked on this.

{embed="events/.upcoming" limit="10" dynamic="off" range_start="today @ noon"}

{!-- end col 12--}

Here is our website: http://1oaklasvegas.com/home. The upcoming events scroll part is where I'm having issues with. Where old events that ended early in the morning doesn't fall off until midnight.

Amy

Comment: So it looks like it has something to do with the dates. Most of our events are from 10:30pm - 4am. So that is why it stays until midnight then drops off. Know how to fix that?

Comment: Deactivated how? By changing status or changing the value of a field? Does the home page have page cache enabled? Please, update your question with more details.

Comment: You know, I don't really know. I will have to ask the social media person how it works. I'm thinking its suppose to automatically just disappear after 12am regardless what time we say it ends. For example, our next event is tonight and ends at saturday 4am. We want it to drop off once it hits 4am but instead it doesn't drop off till midnight. http://1oaklasvegas.com/home

Comment: I **guess** it's _configured_ to check for the day of the event compared to the current day, but we need more info to help you. If you can't provide more info, there's a lot developers here that could be hired just to fix this. Maybe, to fix this by yourself doesn't worth the risk of you to break your site by mistake.

If you can get more info, please update your question and we'll try to help you.

Comment: Also, please confirm if you're using the Solspace Calendar module or not. If you have some template code to show, please do so as well. However, I agree with Robson, maybe it's worth hiring someone with some experience in this, especially if you're dealing with a live site that could potentially break if you're not familiar with the system.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that kind of power to say hey lets hire someone to fix this and they most likely will not hire anyone to fix this. Yes this is the solspace calendar. I don't see any code besides the code to embed the events that gets added. I'm just wondering how to fix the timing issue where the event should fall off at a set time vs it falling off at midnight that day. I'm assuming it doesn't happen to anyone? What file would you recommend me looking at?

Comment: Please, show us the template which shows the events. Can you find that? If so, please, update your question.

Comment: <section class="eventsBg eventsHome">
   <div class="col12 float-center relative">
    <a class="browse prev left" style="top:145px;"></a>
    <a class="browse next right" style="top:145px;"></a>
          
     <div class="clear spacing"></div>
    <div class="scrollable" id="eventsScrollable">
     
     <div class="items">
     {embed="events/.upcoming" limit="10" dynamic="off" range_start="today @ noon"}
     </div>
    </div>
       
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </div> {!-- end col 12--}
   
   <div class="clear"></div>
  </section>

Comment: I tried adding the range_start but that doesn't seem to help at all. Still drops off at midnight the following day.

Comment: @user3076, we need the content of the `events/.upcoming` template. And, please, add all of this to your question, not to the comments.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by you need the content.

Comment: Copy and paste your `events/.upcoming` template code into your original question above. Do not add it as a comment.

Comment: I already did that.

Comment: Okies, I figured it out.

Comment: No, Amy. I need the template called `.upcoming` that is inside the directory/group `events`. This is the file that lists your events.

Comment: Yeah I already figured it out. I went through some other forum and learned about the events.group directory. So I was able to fix it. I don't know anything about EE and how things are set up but I think I understand now.

Comment: Good to know, Amy! But, please, update your question, post your own answer and mark it as right, so you can help others. Thanks!